# kolla-ansible TLS deploiement failed

Tags: ssl, ansible, openstack

I try to deploy Openstack Ussuri with kolla-ansible and self signed certificates in all-in-one configuration.

The deployement fails with the following error :

```
no appropriate commonName or subjectAltName fields were found'
```

I suspect a failure caused by certificates verification.

How can I say to kolla-ansible not verifying server certificates.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I go a bit futher by modifying the template of certificate genaration for the backend.
I mofified the /opt/kolla-ansible/share/kolla-ansible/ansible/roles/certificates/templates/openssl-kolla-backend.cnf.j2
to add commonName = {{ kolla_internal_fqdn }}

Comment: But now I get the error :
SSL exception connecting to https://10.10.0.120:8774/v2.1/os-services?binary=nova-compute: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.10.0.120', port=8774): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2.1/os-services?binary=nova-compute (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:852)'),))"

It seems that nova is not deployed with TLS/SSL support !

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake, if you are interested.

If you want to deploy an all-in-one configuration with TLS support, enable the haproxy and set the kolla_internal_vip_address on another address than the one dedicated to your server.